# java.security.AccessControlException in Spring Application

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a file described in *src/resources/database-context.xml*

```
<context:property-placeholder 
location="file:#{systemProperties['CONF_DIR']}/environment.properties"
ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

For some reason its not being read, and I get the following error...

```
14:15:32.454 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \environment.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.mizuho.ats.main.LoanAdjust.main(LoanAdjust.java:80)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \environment.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

But the real reason might an access control issue...

```
14:15:32.282 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.SpringProperties - Could not retrieve system property 'spring.beaninfo.ignore': java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "spring.beaninfo.ignore" "read")
14:15:32.298 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer#0'
14:15:32.298 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer#0'
14:15:32.298 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
14:15:32.298 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.SpringProperties - Could not retrieve system property 'spring.getenv.ignore': java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "spring.getenv.ignore" "read")
```

And its failing to read the entries...

```
14:43:45.274 [main] INFO org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Caught AccessControlException when accessing system property [CONF_DIR];
    its value will be returned [null]. Reason: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "CONF_DIR" "read")
```

Of course, the file exists in the path. And there is a security policy file with the following specification...(may be its not even loading.)

```
grant {
    // Allow everything
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

The original application was developed in an environment having only JDK 1.7, and I am working on a JDK 1.8 environment, though I have explicity specified 1.7 JDK in the compile settings and 1.7 JRE in the Run Configurations JRE settings.

What might be causing this? Any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in creating an entry in your lib/security policy file of your JRE.

Usually for Spring applications, the src/resources policy file will suffice, but for some reason it was not, especially when the logs/other files were going to be read from locations outside the project folders. Its a run time exception.